# JavaScript - post request to Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony-3.4

I wrote a function to sent a simple request trough Controller via JavaScript in my Symfony project. My alert is triggered when I refresh the page and it should be triggered when I am clicking the Submit button.

What I am doing wrong?

Button:

```
<button type="button" id="request"  data-path="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('change_status', object) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

My JS code:

```
var path = $("#request").attr("data-path");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path,
        data: {id : 'aaa'},
        "success":function(data){
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
```

and Controller:

```
 $data = $request->request->get('request');

 return new Response($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `onclick` property in your `button` and wrap your JS code in a function that will be called by this `onclick`